# can't connect to local mqtt server at node from react application

Tags: reactjs, mqtt

```js
let mqqturl = "mqtt://localhost:1888";

let mqttClient = mqtt.connect(mqqturl);

mqttClient.on("connect",()=>{
    console.log("connection established...");
})
```

I have my code in react index.js file as above.I am trying to connect my react app to local mqtt server which is created within node.I also tried by replacing localhost with my IP but no luck.The console I am getting in my react app at browser.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use native MQTT from with in the browser. To use MQTT you need to use it over websockets.

Assuming your broker is set up with MQTT over websockets enabled you need to change the URL from `mqtt://localhost:1883` to `ws://localhost:[some other port number]`

Comment: Yes .You are right .I just changed port and it worked for me ..Thank you